# In a template that uses Bootstrap, how do you split an array into two columns?

Tags: angular, angular-template

In an Angular component, I have an array of values. In the related template, I want to display those values in two columns. The template uses the Bootstrap framework.

Since Angular templates require starting and ending tags in loops, you cannot print `</div><div class="row">` to give you precision line breaks. What is the correct approach to splitting array over two columns?

A pseudo-code example (this does *not* work):

```
public foobars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

----

<ng-container *ngFor="let foo of foobars; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="i % 2 === 0; else secondColumn">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">{{foo}}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #secondColumn>
        <div class="col-md-6">{{foo}}</div>
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Really complicated. it is possible for you to split a foobars array like this `[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e']]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to put `a,c,e` in first column and you are using Bootstrap, you can just do it using auto break in Bootstrap grid system.

Just don't break by `row` class. Put every `col` element in a row instead.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let foo of foobars" class="col-6">{{foo}}</div>
</div>
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krway8

Comment: Thanks, it really helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You Might want something like

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let foo of foobars; let i = index
  <div *ngIf="i % 2 === 0; then column1 else column2"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <ng-template #column1>
        <!-- column 1, here put the col-* class -->
      </ng-template>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <ng-template #column2>
        <!-- column 2, here put the col-* class -->
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>      
</ng-container>
```

Comment: but in each ngFor it will create a new row right? Then how to avoid it

Comment: I think we can put the row div on top level, before the loop.

Comment: his requirement is to print `a` and `b` in a first row and `c` and `d` in second row. but using ngFor. how can you achieve this?

Comment: I have update the answer. I think it will work now.